# Batch renaming files and directories with bash

Tags: bash, rename

I have several folders with mp3 files organised by genre, artist and album.
I want to have the genres in capital letters, but everything below in the hierarchy with lowercase letters and devoid of special characters and whitespaces.

For this I have written a bash script, which accepts the path to the folder within all subfolders and files should be renamed:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Aufruf:
#$ ./alles.klein '/home/anja/Musik/HOERSPIELE' 

PFAD=$1

cd $PFAD

depthVarations=("-maxdepth 1 -type d" "-depth -type d" "-depth -type f") 

for i in "${depthVarations[@]}"
do
    :
    date
    echo $i
    find  .  $i -exec rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' {} \;
    
    date
    echo $i
    find  .  $i -exec rename 's/(.*)(\.\/)(.*)/$1\/\L$3/' {} \;
    
    #.... several more regex variations
done
```

My problem is that it tries to change the whole path and not just the part I want to have changed e.g.

```
/home/anja/Musik/ORIENTALISCHES/A-wa
```

becomes now

```
/home/anja/musik/orientalisches/a-wa  #everything is lowercase
```

the desired result would be:

```
/home/anja/Musik/ORIENTALISCHES/a-wa
```

As you see `musik/orientalisches` is changed to lowercase, too.
I hoped that by "cd" into the right folder I might get only the path below, but it doesn't seem to work that way.

Comment: I thought, I did that. Bit I adapt my description to make it better understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `-execdir` instead of `-exec` to lowercase only filename:

```sh
find . "$i" -execdir rename -n 'y/A-Z/a-z/' {} \;
```

Or else you may use this `rename` command:

```sh
find . "$i" -exec rename 's~^(.*/)(.+)~$1\L$2~' {} \;
```

or

```sh
find . "$i" -execdir rename 's~(.+)~\L$1~' {} \;
```

Comment: The first example gives me errors in the output:
`Can't rename ./warda /warda: Invalid cross-device link` I guess it cannpot rename it, since it already exists? 
But it did the trick and renamed only, what I wanted  to rename.